# javascript function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two javascript function **myfunction()** and **submitform()** in my script.

```
<script>
var intervalID = 0;
function myFunction(interval) {
if(interval == 1) {
    if(intervalID != 0) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        intervalID = 0;
    }
}
else if(intervalID == 0){
    intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
        getdetails();
        $('.View').load('alert.php').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function getdetails(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "detail.php"
    }).done(function( result ) {
        $("#msg").html( result );
    });
}

function submitform(){
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var alertid = $("#alertid").val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "analytic.php",
        data:{cmt:comment,alert_id:alertid}
    }).done(function( result ) {
    $("#msg").html( result );
    });
    return false;
}
</script>

<form method = "POST" onsubmit = "return submitform();" >
  <textarea onFocus = "myFunction(1)" onBlur = "myFunction(0)" style="margin: 0px 0px 8.99305534362793px; width: 570px; height: 50px;" rows = "6" cols = "40" id = "comment"></textarea> <br />
  <input type = "hidden" placeholder="Enter Maximium 100 Words" id = "alertid" value = "102" />
  <input  type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Comment" />
</form>
```

**submitform()** function call on `osubmit` event in form and **myfunction()** call on `onfocus` and `onblur` in `textarea` tag.
when i call **submitform()** function then **myfunction()** function stops its working on `onfocus` and `onblur` event

Comment: Any errors in the error console?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher No there is no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

just use `submitform()` instead of `return submitform()`

```
<form method = "POST" onsubmit = "submitform();" >
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form  onsubmit = "submitform();" >
```

JS

```
function submitform(){
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var alertid = $("#alertid").val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "analytic.php",
        data:{cmt:comment,alert_id:alertid}
    }).done(function( result ) {
    $("#msg").html( result );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

friends this code is working now.
I found my problem.
correct code as follow..

```
 <script>
    var intervalID = 0;
    function myFunction(interval) {
    if(interval == 1) {
        if(intervalID != 0) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            intervalID = 0;
        }
    }
    else if(intervalID == 0){
        intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
            getdetails();
            $('.View').load('alert.php').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function getdetails(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "detail.php"
        }).done(function( result ) {
            $("#msg").html( result );
        });
    }

    function submitform(){
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var alertid = $("#alertid").val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "analytic.php",
            data:{cmt:comment,alert_id:alertid}
        });
        return false;
    }
    </script>

    <form method = "POST" onsubmit = "return submitform();" >
      <textarea onFocus = "myFunction(1)" onBlur = "myFunction(0)" style="margin: 0px 0px 8.99305534362793px; width: 570px; height: 50px;" rows = "6" cols = "40" id = "comment"></textarea> <br />
      <input type = "hidden" placeholder="Enter Maximium 100 Words" id = "alertid" value = "102" />
      <input  type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Comment" />
    </form>
```